# URL Object add or remove params

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to add value of each checkbox to `URL` searchParams, first time when I check a checkbox it works good, but when I reload page, it not work anymore, what I have done wrong? I mean it works when it is `state` but after page load, not working, how can I fix this?

```js
function setURL(query){
//var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
var url = window.location.href;
let newURL = new URL(url);
newURL.searchParams.append('brands', query)
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newURL);
}

function checkURL(){
var url = window.location.href;
let newURL = new URL(url);
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newURL);
     if(newURL.searchParams.has('brands')){
let currentBrands = newURL.searchParams.get('brands');
let brandsArray = currentBrands.split(',');
brandsArray.map(function(v,i){
jQuery('input[name="pa_brand"][value="'+v+'"]').click();
});
     }
}
checkURL();
let array = [];

jQuery('input[name="pa_brand"]').change(function(){
        let value = this.value;
        let id = array.indexOf(value);

        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
        array.push(value)
        } else {
        array.splice(id,  1);
        }
setURL(array.toString())
console.log(array)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="pa_brand" value="116"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="pa_brand" value="117"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="pa_brand" value="118"/>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the reload and provide a more technical explanation of *"not work anymore"* which is quite meaningless without more debugging details and if errors exist or not

Comment: @charlietfl when url is `site.com/page` and it will add values like this `site.com/page?brands=116` but when I reload this page with current url, then I check another checkbox, it not append value to search params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all replace `newURL.searchParams.append('brands', query)` with `newURL.searchParams.set('brands', query)`. It will solve your problem also in the `checkURL` put initial value to `array` variable. I edited your code after these two changes and everythin seems ok.

```
let array = [];
function setURL(query){
//var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
var url = window.location.href;
let newURL = new URL(url);
newURL.searchParams.set('brands', query)
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newURL);
}

function checkURL(){
var url = window.location.href;
let newURL = new URL(url);
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newURL);
     if(newURL.searchParams.has('brands')){
let currentBrands = newURL.searchParams.get('brands');
let brandsArray = currentBrands.split(',');
array = brandsArray;
brandsArray.map(function(v,i){
jQuery('input[name="pa_brand"][value="'+v+'"]').click();
});
     }
}
checkURL();


jQuery('input[name="pa_brand"]').change(function(){
        let value = this.value;
        let id = array.indexOf(value);

        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
        array.push(value)
        } else {
        array.splice(id,  1);
        }
setURL(array.toString())
console.log(array)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wondering why still not working.

Comment: There was a syntax problem in my answer, I missed `})` at the end of the, could you try it again and check it works or not.

Comment: No, thats fine, I solved first time I used. But still not update params after page load, odd!

Comment: I use it https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bzrm25?file=index.html it's working without problem